# I broke a promise with a terrible condition. WIll Allah still forgive me?

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness

During the holy month of Ramadan, I had sinned many times, and I really regret it. I promised Allah that I would never sin again, but I broke it. I apologised to Allah too. I couldn't control myself. One time, I made a promise to Allah, and I said 'Allah, if I sin one more time, you may never forgive me, or listen to me', and I broke the promise. I made the same promise, and broke it again. Astaghfirullah I'm so scared. Am I doomed? Will Allah still forgive me and listen to me? I really regret making that promise and I sincerely regret breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

Never! Allah ta'la forgives all sins.
"...o my servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning] do not despair from the mercy of Allah, indeed he forgives all sins, indeed he is the forgiving the merciful" (zumar ayah 53).

Sister, never lose hope in the mercy of Allah. The devil wants you to despair and think Allah will never forgive you. The name Iblees means losing hope. He wants you to lose hope, which is why Allah ta'la called him Iblees and because he despaired from the mercy of Allah. If you despair from his mercy, then you are being like the devil. So, never despair of his mercy.

But this does not mean that you keep sinning and say "Allah will forgive me. He is merciful". You can not do that. You have to repent sincerely and try your very best to leave the sins you are committing. After Allah ta'la says to never despair of his mercy in zumar ayah 53, he follows it up and says "and submit to your Lord before the punishment comes upon you...". This tells us that you can not just keep sinning and saying "Allah is merciful, he will forgive me." May Allah guide us all and forgive our sins. Ameen.

Answer (score -1):

Never think that! Never! Wallah Allah will never reject us he says in the Quran" oh my servants do not despair in the mercy of Allah..indeed he Forgives all sins" Don't you know that Allah forgave a person who killed 100 people...he's mercy is bigger then All sins..even shirk if one repents before death and never repeats it again...have hope in his mercy indeed seeking forgiveness is the most easiest way to JANNAH!! if my answer helped then please upvote it..JazakAllah